# jQuery hide multiple objects with one method

Tags: jquery

I have multirow table and I want to hide some of them on click event. How can I do it with single method

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function createInputForm(){
            var rtype = $('#rtype').val();
            var md = $('#tr_md'),reg = $('#tr_reg'),trans = $('#tr_trans'),;

                $('#table_input_new tr').fadeIn();
                if(rtype=='A'){
                    $(md,reg).fadeOut();
                }
                else if(rtype=='B'){
                    $(reg,trans).fadeOut();
                }
       }


       $('#rtype').change(createInputForm);
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to add one jQuery collection to another:

```
if (rtype == 'A') {
    md.add(reg).fadeOut();
}
else if (rtype == 'B') {
    reg.add(trans).fadeOut();
}
```